# I can't make promise function

Tags: javascript

I try find this Answer more 4 hours,
I have homework but can't Answer because I think all option don't correct.,

A web developer is creating a function to return a promise. Consider the following JavaScript promise function:

```
function greeting() { return Promise.resolve("Welcome"); }
```

How can the developer create an asynchronous function that returns a promise?

```
A. return "Welcome"; }

B. function greeting() { return "Welcome"; }

C. function greeting() { return resolve("Welcome"); }

D. await function greeting() { return "Welcome"; }
```

I was always thinking it would be the last answer D but don't sure,
No Resolve Without Promise
And sure there is no Await before the function

Comment: None of them, currently. If you set `const resolve = Promise.resolve` then it's C. If you replace `await` in D with `async`, then D is correct

Comment: If, during those 4 hours, you've tested each option and all of them fail then, well, all of them are incorrect.